# Binding Odata Xamarin Xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, odata

I'm having trouble with binding a ListView from Odata, when I was working with local Db I was able to do the data binding returning a list in my ModelView class into my list variable through the get method, but with the Odata the method is Async, so I'am not able to return the list, and some how if i fill the variable in the method, it doesn't work, and at this point I cant find the solution, if someone could help me, I will really appreciate it, here is my code so far:

ViewModel class:

```
public class Page1ViewModel
{


    public string Nombre { set; get; }
    public string Direccion { set; get; }
    public string Descripcion { set; get; }
    public string Logo { set; get; }

   public List<Restaurant> RestaurantDb { get; set; }

   public async void GetRestaurant()
    {
        String str = "";
        try
        {
            var x = ODataDynamic.Expression;
            var client = new ODataClient("http://192.168.0.9/WSTestDev/WSTestDev.svc/");
            var packages = await client.FindEntriesAsync("Restaurant");
            foreach  (var package in  packages)
            {
                var  rt =  new Restaurant 
                {
                    Nombre = package["Nombre"].ToString(),
                    Direccion = package["Direccion"].ToString(),
                    Descripcion = package["Descripcion"].ToString(),
                    Logo = package["Logo"].ToString()
                };

                RestaurantDb.Add(rt);

            }



        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

            str = err.ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

View Class:

```
 public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1ViewModel vm;
    public Page1()
    {   
        vm = new Page1ViewModel();
        vm.GetRestaurant();
        BindingContext = vm;
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `List<Restaurant>`, use `ObservableCollection<Restaurant>`.  It behaves similarly to List, but will notify the UI of any changes to it's contents so that the UI can update.

Alternately, you could `await vm.GetRestaurant()`, but that will require more restructuring of your code.

Comment: What would I need to get the "await vm.GetRestaurant()"? because I just use some breakpoints in the view class, and it runs all the instructions, but  although the "GetRestaurant" method is above the "binding" and the "initialize", the method run after them, and I'm guessing that's the problem(?)

Comment: You can't call an async method from a constructor, and you can return void from an async method.  You would need to modify your code to fix both of those things.  Or just change List to an ObservableCollection